# How to close the Navigation drawer in android

Tags: android, android-menu, android-navigation, android-drawer

My application has a navigation drawer. From drawer options, I am opening different activities.  At that time a blank screen is displayed before the new Activity.

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.nav_message:

        Intent newAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FeedbackActivity.class);
        startActivity(newAct);
    
       break;


}


drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
return true;
```

}

As per some investigations, I found like we need to remove the below code from this. Tried the same and working fine.

```
drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
    return true;
```

But when I click the back button from the new activity, the drawer is still open status. How can I close without that black screen?

Comment: Move the `drawer.close` before you startActivity, doesn't that do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried passing `GRAVITY.START` as a parameter to `drawer.close(int gravity)`, like this:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.nav_message:

        Intent newAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FeedbackActivity.class);
        startActivity(newAct);
    
       break;


}



drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
return true;
```

And don't forget to initialize the drawer object with `findViewById()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I initialized the drawer object as final. Issue fixed by removing final declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable drawer menu animation and call closeDrawer before starting new activity

```
    drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT, false);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.nav_message:

        Intent newAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FeedbackActivity.class);
        startActivity(newAct);
    
       break;


}

return true;
```

Comment: Unable to add the drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT, false);
after switch without case label.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I edited it, you are right.